# Python/JSON : I want to go to a specific thing when it can't find it in a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm actually making my discord bot and I wanted to make a command to know plane informations. I made it but know i want to put plane photos depending on the company.
I tried to do that:

```
if plane_data["data"][f"{flight_companie}"] == "FedEx" or "Ryanair" or "SWISS" or "Air France" or "SWISS" or "British Airways":
  plane_photo = plane_data["data"][flight_companie]
else:
  plane_photo = plane_data["data"]["unknown"]
```

Unknown is equal to a url photo that says there is no plane photos.

When i try with UPS it gives me that out:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'UPS Airlines'
```

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if plane_data["data"][f"{flight_companie}"] == "FedEx" or "Ryanair"...
```

will always evaluate to `True`. This is because a string like "Ryanair" is truthy. Meaning it becomes true when converted to a boolean. So your line is equivialent to

```
if plane_data["data"][f"{flight_companie}"] == "FedEx" or True or True or True ...
```

`or` can not be used in this situation. I would use

```
if plane_data["data"][f"{flight_companie}"] in ["FedEx","Ryanair","SWISS","Air France","SWISS","British Airways"]:
```

instead.